# text aligning by dxf groups

Tags: autocad, text-alignment, autolisp

I have a bunch of text lines , iam drawing\showing them one in each line using entmake procedure. and for that i provide a insertion point , i want the text to be aligned from the left , the problem is that the lines lengths are different and the insertion point seems to be the center of text.

i was thinking of using the length of the text and the size\height of the text to calculate the pad i need to make so the text is aligned . if iam in the right path i cant find out how to do the calculation .

if I am not please help.
here is how i make text entities:

```
  (defun text(point text)

         (list ( cons 0  "TEXT")

           (cons 11 point)
           (cons 10  point)
           (cons 40  0.4)
           (cons 1  text)
           (cons 41  1.0)
           (cons 72  4)
               (cons 73  0)
      ) )
```

thank you

Comment: Rather than attempting to calculate the position of a center-justified text insertion point, is there any reason you would not simply create left-justified text?

Comment: I suppose the clue is "insertion point seems to be the center of text" Why is that? please paste code of (entmake ...) You are using.
My sample would be '(entmake (list
  '(0 . "TEXT")
  '(100 . "AcDbEntity")
  '(100 . "AcDbText")
  (cons 1 "GO GO GO!!!")
  (cons 10 (getpoint))
))'
And aligment is left bottom

Comment: Lee Mac :- yest there is , my program will create a lot of entities (including text) i dont want to use (command "text" ...) .

Comment: CAD Developer : i tried the line you suggested i didnt work for me - the entity did not appear .

Comment: i found the problem , the justification can be controlled by the groups 72 and 73 not just by (cammand "text"  "j"...). thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create left-justified single-line `TEXT` entities using the following `entmakex` expression:

```lisp
(defun mytext ( ins hgt str )
    (entmakex
        (list
           '(000 . "TEXT")
            (cons 010 ins)
            (cons 040 hgt)
            (cons 001 str)
        )
    )
)
```

Which may be called for example:

```lisp
(mytext '(1.0 1.0 0.0) 0.4 "This is a test")
```

Here:

- DXF group `0` is the entity type
- DXF group `10` is the text insertion point
- DXF group `40` is the text height
- DXF group `1` is the text content

These four DXF groups are the minimum groups required to create a single-line `TEXT` entity.

For **left-justified** single-line text, only DXF group `10` is required to specify the position; for **all other justifications**, DXF group `11` represents the text alignment point and the value of DXF group `10` (the insertion point) is ignored if supplied (though, the group must be present).

For example, for middle-center justified single-line text, you might use the following:

```lisp
(defun mytext ( ins hgt str )
    (entmakex
        (list
           '(000 . "TEXT")
            (cons 010 ins)
            (cons 011 ins)
            (cons 040 hgt)
            (cons 001 str)
           '(072 . 1)
           '(073 . 2)
        )
    )
)
```

Here:

- DXF group `0` is the entity type
- DXF group `10` is the text insertion point (used if both DXF `72` and `73` are zero)
- DXF group `11` is the text alignment point (used if either DXF `72` or `73` are non-zero)
- DXF group `40` is the text height
- DXF group `1` is the text content
- DXF group `72` determines the horizontal alignment
- DXF group `73` determines the vertical alignment

If you want to create single-line text which adheres to the properties of the active UCS (for example, created in the UCS construction plane, rotated to align with the UCS x-axis), you can use the following:

```lisp
(defun mytext ( ins hgt str )
    (
        (lambda ( ocs )
            (entmakex
                (list
                   '(000 . "TEXT")
                    (cons 010 (trans ins 1 ocs))
                    (cons 050 (angle '(0.0 0.0) (trans (getvar 'ucsxdir) 0 ocs t)))
                    (cons 040 hgt)
                    (cons 001 str)
                    (cons 210 ocs)
                )
            )
        )
        (trans '(0.0 0.0 1.0) 1 0 t)
    )
)
```

This assumes that the insertion point will be supplied relative to the active UCS, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun c:test ( )
    (mytext
        (progn
            (initget 1)
            (getpoint "\nSpecify insertion point: ")
        )
        (progn
            (initget 7)
            (getdist "\nSpecify text height: ")
        )
        (getstring t "\nSpecify text content: ")
    )
)
```

A reference for all of the DXF groups applicable to a `TEXT` entity may be found [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-62E5383D-8A14-47B4-BFC4-35824CAE8363).